# Не работают файловые библиотеки Android 10

Tags: android, android-scoped-storage

У меня есть программа, у которой в настройках есть функция, где нужно выбрать папку. Я использовал библиотеку bartwell/ExFilePicker. Проблема заключается в том, что ниже приведенный код не работает на Android 10, но прекрасно работает на прошлых версиях. В чем заключается проблема, что то не дописано или это особенности 10ки?

```
public void onFolderClick(View view) {
    ExFilePicker exFilePicker = new ExFilePicker();
    exFilePicker.setChoiceType(ExFilePicker.ChoiceType.DIRECTORIES);
    exFilePicker.setCanChooseOnlyOneItem(true);

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.audioFolder_pref:
            key = AUDIO;
            break;
        case R.id.picFolder_pref:
            key = PIC;
            break;
        case R.id.textFolder_pref:
            key = TEXT;
            break;
    }

    exFilePicker.start(this, EX_FILE_PICKER_RESULT);
}

String pathStr;
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == EX_FILE_PICKER_RESULT && data != null) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri file = data.getData();
            //получить путь папки
            pathStr = file.getPath();

            switch (key) {
                case AUDIO:
                    userPref.setAudioFolder(pathStr);
                    break;
                case PIC:
                    userPref.setPicFolder(pathStr);
                    break;
                case TEXT:
                    userPref.setTextFolder(pathStr);
                    break;
            }

            setFolderText();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все правильно. Не будет работать. Начиная с Android Q (API level=29) введено понятие [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage#scoped-storage) - в соответствии с которым сильно ограничен доступ к файлам во внешнем хранилище.

[bartwell/ExFilePicker](https://github.com/bartwell/ExFilePicker) - написан в 2013 году и уже морально устарел.